# mount -a does not mount Fstab file

Tags: mount, nfs

I have the following in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

sv-01:/mnt/UEF/home/user/Videos/complete /home/user/Videos nfs defaults,noauto,user 0 0
```

and when I issue the command `sudo mount -a -v`, I get the following output

```
mount: proc already mounted on /proc
mount: /dev/mmcblk0p1 already mounted on /boot
nothing was mounted
```

but when I copy paste the above segment of code and issue the below command, the folder mounts perfectly.

```
sudo mount sv-01:/mnt/UEF/home/user/Videos/complete /home/user/Videos
```

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified "noauto" parameter for sv-01:/mnt/UEF/home/user/Videos/complete.

From mount manual:

> mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]
>
> (usually given in a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in
>   fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper
>   options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose line
>   contains the noauto keyword. Adding the -F option will make mount
>   fork, so that the filesystems are mounted simultaneously.

Comment: That did it. Thank you

Comment: @shekharsuman calm down. I still got three minutes to go (6 at the time you wrote that ;-)